# How to write a ANSI C user-defined function that returns a specific line from a text file?

Tags: c, file-io

How to write a ANSI C user-defined function that returns a specific line from a text file?

```
char * ReadFromFile(const char * fileName, int line)
{
    //..........
}
```

Comment: do you have access to use fopen fread and such?

Comment: Better declaration: `int ReadFromFile(const char *fileName, int lineNumber, char *buffer, int buffer_length)`.

Comment: Yes I have access to fopen fread and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
char * ReadFromFile(const char * fileName, int line)
{

  FILE *fp;

  char c;
  char *buffer = malloc( 100 * sizeof(char) );  // change 100 to a suitable value; 
  int buffer_length = 100;                      // eg. max length of line in your file

  int num = 0;

  if(line < 0)   // check for negative  line numbers
  {
    printf("Line number must be 0 or above\n");
    return(NULL);
  }

  if( ( fp = fopen(fileName,"r") ) == NULL )
  {
     printf("File not found");
     return(NULL);
  }

  while(num < line)  // line numbers start from 0
  {
    c = getc(fp);
    if(c == '\n')
    num++;      
  }

  c = getc(fp);

  if(c == EOF)
  {
    printf("Line not found\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return(NULL);
  } 
  else
  {
    ungetc(c,fp);     //push the read character back onto the stream
    fgets(buffer,buffer_length,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return(buffer);
  }
```

}

**Edit:** The boundary conditions suggested by `caf` & `lorenzog` in the comments have been included. Never thought error-proofing could be so tedious! (Still doesn't check for cases where line number is more than `int` can safely hold. This is left as an exercise to OP :)

Comment: @JMSA, alright, I have added the buffer in the function itself.

Comment: you'd better check that line > 0 or get it as unsigned int. And assume line isn't bigger than the maximum value an int has on that architecture. But I think that what I am pointing out has nothing to do with ansi C, hence I'm just making a comment here.

Comment: check EOF but not fopen()? ;)

Comment: @Nyan, I have already answered the question; there's no valid reason to my mind why you should go around handing out -1 because the code doesn't check one particular error case; read my remark to OP, for instance.